# Stopping and wrapping 2 sub AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to call `task()` function from `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` class. The task function contains 2 sub-async task. So the `task()` return immediately from `doInBackground()`.

1. Is it possible to stop(or mark this task done)  this task from anywhere else?
2. How to wrap two sub async task in one.

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: I will post my code tomorrow as I'm away from my pc

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call another AsyncTask from within doInBackground.  As a matter of fact, once you get to a high enough API, you'll get an exception.  You can call another long running method from within AsyncTask without needing to worry about a thread; you're already in a background thread.  If you really feed the need, call another service, but there is no reason to do this.

To stop an AsyncTask, just override OnCancelled.  Then you can just call:

```
task.cancel(true).
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to wait for another process to finish before you move on, you can wait for that process to finish by setting a global variable in your class or application and then doing a Thread sleep until done.  You will not get an ANR because you are already in a background thread and not on the Main UI:

```
private boolean processIsDone = false. 

//then in your method you are calling from AsyncTask: 

private void myLongRunningMethod() { 
       //do your work here....

       //at the end set
       processIsDone = true;

}

//in your AsyncTask: 
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     //do first part of AsyncTask here

     myLongRunningMethod();
     do { 
        try {
           Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
     } while (!processIsDone);

     //finish the process here. 

     return null;   

}
```

Comment: What will happens if funtion return immediately from the doInBackground()? I guess the async task will finish immediately... I want to solve thes probkem5

Comment: @dearvivekkumar - Not sure I understand - are you saying you want to wait for the task to finish?

Comment: Yes.. Exactly this is what i want to do

Comment: @dearvivekkumar.  You can just wait for the process to finish.  This is perfectly fine, you are already in AsyncTask.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks... For your time and reply

Comment: I am still think about some other alternatives so that i can avoid the pooling as i need to show progress dialog for that much duration

Comment: You can't do publishProgress()?

Comment: http://rorraja.blogspot.in/2012/03/show-progress-dialog-inside-asynctask.html?m=1

Comment: I have got the above link, but still don't know if this work. I will test tomorrow. Please share your opinion about it, it will be helpful.... Thanks

Comment: @dearvivekkumar How do you know AsyncFacebook is an AsyncTask?

Comment: I was just guessing... I will be trying today.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the question exactly but maybe this can help. Use this class in your Activity like this:

```
myTask = new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
And cancel this way:
myTask.cancel(true);
```

This is the code of the class:

```
private class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object , Object ,String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            // Do Before execute the main task
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Object... param) {
            //Execute the main task and return for example and String
            return res;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // You can use the String returned by the method doInBackground and     process it
    }

}
```

Hope it's help

Comment: The function whi h i need to call is async, so the doInBackground returns immediately. So i want the AsyncTask to run till i stop it from my async task callback.

Answer (score 0):

About your first question, you can catch event when your task is cancelled by `onCancelled()` method. try like this:

```
private CancelTask extends AsyncTask {

    private boolean cancelled = false;
    protected void onCancelled() {
        cancelled = true;
    }

    protected Object doInBackground(Object... obj) {
        do {
            // do something...

        }while(!cancelled)
    }
}
```

and call `AsyncTask.cancel(true);` when you want to stop.

```
CancelTask task = new CancelTask();
task.execute();
...
task.cancel(true);
```

And about second question, I want to know how you handle two "Sub-AsyncTask"s.

I will try to find a solution after you update your code.